# ansible: how to copy files from a linked directory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a symbolically linked folder in linux and would like to copy the contents of the folder to a folder on a remote machine.  I tried so far using the synchronize command because I am trying to copy the entire tree, folders and files.
When I run the synchronize command, it is creating the folder as a symbolic link and the folder is empty.  How can I copy the contents of the symbolic link without creating a symbolic link?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use

```
  copy_links: yes
```

with synchronize module.

"Copy symlinks as the item that they point to (the referent) is copied, rather than the symlink."

[synchronize module Ref](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/modules/synchronize_module.html)